# Parsing through a text to remove Proper nouns and email content in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to perform a certain kind of text cleaning.

Below is the code i use for doing the same:

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
import os
import nltk
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'username/pswd@10.203.97.86:1521/PRD'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = "select ID,SUMMARY from text_table"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
cursordata=cur.fetchall()
tbl=pd.DataFrame(cursordata, columns=["ID", "SUMMARY"])
NOOFTICKETS=len(tbl.index)
print(NOOFTICKETS)

for counter in range(0,len(tbl.index)):
     print counter+1
     ticketid = tbl['ID'][counter]
     sentence = tbl['SUMMARY'][counter]
     tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
     cleanSentence = [word for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos != 'NNP']
     cur.execute("update text_table set summary_tuned = '"+'   '.join(cleanSentence)+"' where id = '"+ticketid+"'")
     conn.commit()
```

Sample of what I get after performing the above actions:

Old summary:

> TEP  IN04 Company code payment run execution issue  Dear Team   we executed the payment on 28th June 2016 with run ID IN04A but still the payment not been executed  Please check and do the needful asap   Thanks Thenna

Cleansed summary:

> code payment run execution issue we executed the payment on 28th 2016 with run but still the payment not been executed check and do the needful asap thanks

Now, what the above code does is it removes all the words starting with a capital letter probably because it considers them as proper nouns. But I want only the name to be removed.

Also, is there a way of cleaning the email content if any from the text? Is there anyway Python recognizes email content through a package?

Comment: The obvious way is to have a database of names, and use that to decide what to remove. I also don't understand what you mean by "cleaning the email content if any from the text". What is "email content"?

Comment: Hi Ken..email content meaning subject, from etc which comes along with the text since we are extracting data from a client DB. 
And each account has a different set of names, so having a database of names does not seem like a feasible option in the long run.